# Python: how to find the occurrence of single character using while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def x(s, c):
    num = 0
    while (blank....here should enter some code):
        num = num + 1
    return num
```

in this function, s means a string(i.e 'banana'), c means a single character(i.e 'a'), if c is in s, then return the number of c's occurrence; if c is not in s, return the length of s. 
There just one row after while, so what should i enter into?

Comment: `s.count(c) or len(s)` – no need for a loop.

Comment: It took most of your question to explain your single-letter identifier names, including the name of your function. Why not use better names?

Comment: So x("AAA", "A") is 3 and x("AAA", "Z") is also 3?

Answer (score 0):

As @poke already mentioned all you need is `return s.count(c) or len(s)`

```
def x(s, c):
    return s.count(c) or len(s)
```

or

```
def x(s, c):
    return s.lower().count(c.lower()) or len(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not want to use any of the predefined string methods, you can  iterate manually on the string and count the occurrences of the wanted character as well as each position encountered:

```
def x(s, c):
    occ = 0
    tot = 0
    it = iter(s)
    while True:
        try:
            if next(it) == c:
                occ += 1
        except StopIteration:
            return occ or tot
        finally:
            tot += 1

print(x('hello world','l'))
print(x('hello world','y'))
```

which produces

```
3
11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def x(s, c):
    num = 0
    for char in s: # Iterate through each character in the string
        if char == c: # If that character matches c
            num += 1 # Add 1 to num
    return num if num else len(s)
```